# Card to make a DDR3 "hard drive"

Tags: memory, data-storage

I want to update my old PC with 24 Gb of DDR3 to a new PC with DDR4.

Because I do not want to throw away that large amount of DDR3 memory, I want to make a DDR3 drive, to use as temporary storage.

I need a recommendation for PCIE cards that use DDR3 DIMM to emulate a storage drive.
The OS will be Windows 10 64b, and I want a cheap card.
I do not need external power or batteries, because is only for temporary storage.

I had been looking for on Amazon, and didn’t found anything. I don’t even know what is the name of what I should be searching for.

I found that Gigabyte used to make a product, named  i-RAM, but is discontinued.

Comment: Why do you want a RAM Drive? It really isn't worth the trouble. Besides, I don't think this kind of hardware is available (anymore) because there are way better methods of storing data (SSDs for one).

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Windows would automatically use it for swap file, reducing SSD wear. I have lots of uses for temporary files.